# golang not printing all the HTML

Tags: html, go, parsing

I'm trying to get the HTML of a website but it does not show me all the HTML. I have tried using python and it shows everything fine. However it does not in golang.

Here is my code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    res, err := http.Get("https://golf-land.fr/37-chaussures-de-golf-homme/s-6/marque_2-jordan_golf")
    res.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36")
    res.Header.Add("Accept", `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9`)
    res.Header.Add("sec-ch-ua", `"Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"`)
    res.Header.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", "macOS")
    res.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
    res.Header.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate")
    res.Header.Add("Accept-Language", "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7")
    res.Header.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document")
    res.Header.Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
    res.Header.Add("Host", "golf-land.fr")
    res.Header.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
    res.Header.Add("Cookie", "_gcl_au=1.1.1697272256.1647946908; _ga=GA1.2.1737361814.1647946908; _fbp=fb.1.1647946908571.1339014446; browserupdateorg=pause; PHPSESSID=pl50pcpu4h09pqqgnf9m22o4p6; PrestaShop-90e2722599b5b00d1f7517fdd071a2e0=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; _gid=GA1.2.562051467.1648368266")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    sb := string(body)
    fmt.Print(sb)
}
```

it is missing the products-row division in the output, which appears in the browser or with python

Comment: Why are you adding may headers in the response? Perhaps you need to add them in the request

Answer (score 1):

The [`http.Get`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17.8#Get) constructs **and sends** the request and then returns the server's response to that request. Setting headers after the request was sent (to its response no less) has NO effect on the already sent request itself. You should use [`http.NewRequest`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17.8#NewRequest) to construct the request, then set the request's headers, and *then* send it with the [`(*http.Client).Do`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17.8#Client.Do) method.

```golang
func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://golf-land.fr/37-chaussures-de-golf-homme/s-6/marque_2-jordan_golf", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36")
    // set the rest of the headers ...
    
    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```